# Get the Uri inside an action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rss

Here's the method of the controller

```
public class FeedController : ControllerBase
    {

        public RssActionResult Rss()
        {
          //........

            List<SyndicationItem> items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
            var photosList = Facade.Photos.Get()
                .Select(x =>
                    new SyndicationItem(
                        x.Title, 
                        x.PreviewPath,
                        new Uri("http://site.com/"+CurrentLocale.CultureName+"/photos/show/" + x.ID + ".html"), x.ID.ToString(),
                        DateTime.UtcNow)
                        );
            //........
            return new RssActionResult() { Feed = feed };
        }

    }
```

How can I avoid the hardcoding of the Uri?

**UPDATE**

```
 routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                "Photos_Route",
                "{culture}/photos/{action}/{id}.html",
                new { controller = "photos", action = "show", culture = defaultCulture }
                );
```

Comment: What is this url? Is it part of your site? Or is it some external url? If it is part of your site how does your route definitions look like? Or is it just a static file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URI is a resource on your own site, and if you have a route defined for it, you can use something similar to this:

```
Url.RouteUrl(new RouteValueDictionary{ {"controller","Photo"}, {"action","show"}, {"Id",x.ID} })
```

There are several overrides for the RouteUrl method.

Otherwise, if that URI is a resource on some other site, you can just store the URI format in web.config, and use string.Format(urlFormatFromWebConfig, x.ID) to generate the URL.

EDIT: More specific, now that you updated with your Route:

```
new Uri(Url.RouteUrl("Photos_Route", new RouteValueDictionary{ {"culture", CurrentLocale.CultureName}, {"ID", x.ID.ToString()} });
```